# How do I mark only changed/deleted/.. files in cornerstone?

Tags: version-control, cornerstone

I am using Cornerstone on Mac OS 10.8.4 and sometimes I need to bulk change many files in Subversion at once.

Cornerstone does have different filters to show only changed/deleted/conflicted/etc. files. But on selecting the filters, also the containing folders of the files are shown. This makes it hard to mark only the changed/deleted/etc. files for Subversion commits on bulk changes, because I have to mark every single one file separately. If I don't do that, also the folders will be deleted or marked for the commit.

Does anybody know how to filter the containing folders from the changed/deleted/etc. filters, so I can mark only affected files?

Comment: But Subversion is directory- (or folder- if you prefer) oriented rather than file-oriented.  You check out a directory to a working copy, you commit changes to (the files in) a directory, if you modify a file the directory containing the file is tagged as modified.  I don't think you'll be able to use Cornerstone to subvert Subversion as you seem to want to.  I don't see this as a problem, more a consequence of working with Subversion.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings: I do not want to change Subversion, I try to figure out how to work with a *GUI* designed to display subversion information. ;)